# Get results from AuditCriterion in new class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-envers, audit-tables

I Know that when you do this code:

```
    AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
    reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Person.class,false,true).getResultList();
```

it returns a tree element array.  I want this 3 elements array to be mapped in a new class:

```
public class PersonNew {

Person person;
DefaultRevisionEntity revision;
RevisionType revisionType;

public PersonNew (Person person, DefaultRevisionEntity revision, RevisionType revisionType) {
    this.person = person;
    this.revision = revision;
    this.revisionType = revisionType;
}
```

}

i know that in criteria an in simple select you can do something like

```
select new com.package.PersonNew () from Person.
```

How does it apply to hibernate envers query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in Envers currently, you will need to do the mapping yourself.